# How to Blacklist Google analytics in Firefox's NoScript?

Tags: firefox, blacklist

I get the yellow warning bottom bar of NoScript all the time I see that Google Analytics is blocked. 
I do not like this behaviour because it disturbs. I would like to have Blacklist but I do not find it in settings, similarly as you have Whitelist.

---

How can you blacklist Google Analytics in Firefox's NoScript?

Comment: [Can Noscript blacklist instead of whitelist?](https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21206895-Can-Noscript-blacklist-instead-of-whitelist)

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually, the solution provided in the thread is secondary solution. It is not primary solution. You cannot Blacklist in NoScript directly. So the answer to this thread is No, you cannot.

Comment: The answer is yes you can, by following the instructions provided. Please don't be pedantic.

Comment: @DavidPostill I disagree with you. I do not accept the answer and removed the addon. I can make better myself.

Comment: <shrug> Your choice.